# Increment shared loop counter in OpenMP for progress reporting

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, raytracing

I want to keep track of total pixels and rays processed by a long running raytracing process. If I update the shared variables every iteration, the process will slow down noticeably because of synchronization. I'd like to keep track of the progress and still get accurate count results at the end. Is there a way to do this with OpenMP for loops?

Here's some code of the loop in question:

```
void Raytracer::trace(RenderTarget& renderTarget, const Scene& scene, std::atomic<int>& sharedPixelCount, std::atomic<int>& sharedRayCount)
{
    int width = renderTarget.getWidth();
    int height = renderTarget.getHeight();
    int totalPixelCount = width * height;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 4096)
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPixelCount; ++i)
    {
        int x = i % width;
        int y = i / width;

        Ray rayToScene = scene.camera.getRay(x, y);
        shootRay(rayToScene, scene, sharedRayCount); // will increment sharedRayCount
        renderTarget.setPixel(x, y, rayToScene.color.clamped());

        ++sharedPixelCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example on how to do it:

```
void Raytracer::trace(RenderTarget& renderTarget, const Scene& scene, std::atomic<int>& sharedPixelCount, std::atomic<int>& sharedRayCount)
{
    int width = renderTarget.getWidth();
    int height = renderTarget.getHeight();
    int totalPixelCount = width * height;
    int rayCount = 0;
    int previousRayCount = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1000) reduction(+:rayCount) firstprivate(previousRayCount)
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPixelCount; ++i)
    {
        int x = i % width;
        int y = i / width;

        Ray rayToScene = scene.camera.getRay(x, y);
        shootRay(rayToScene, scene, rayCount);
        renderTarget.setPixel(x, y, rayToScene.color.clamped());

        if ((i + 1) % 100 == 0)
        {
            sharedPixelCount += 100;
            sharedRayCount += (rayCount - previousRayCount);
            previousRayCount = rayCount;
        }
    }

    sharedPixelCount = totalPixelCount;
    sharedRayCount = rayCount;
}
```

It won't be 100% accurate while the loop is running, but the error is negligible. At the end exact values will be reported.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a chunk size of 4096 for your dynamically scheduled parallel-for loop, why not use that as the granularity for amortizing the counter updates?

For example, something like the following might work.  I didn't test this code and you probably need to add some bookkeeping for `totalPixelCount%4096!=0`.

Unlike the previous answer, this does not add a branch to your loop, other than the one implied by the loop itself, for which many processors have optimized instructions.  It also does not require any extra variables or arithmetic.

```
void Raytracer::trace(RenderTarget& renderTarget, const Scene& scene, std::atomic<int>& sharedPixelCount, std::atomic<int>& sharedRayCount)
{
    int width = renderTarget.getWidth();
    int height = renderTarget.getHeight();
    int totalPixelCount = width * height;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
    for (int j = 0; j < totalPixelCount; j+=4096)
    {
      for (int i = j; i < (i+4096); ++i)
      {
        int x = i % width;
        int y = i / width;

        Ray rayToScene = scene.camera.getRay(x, y);
        shootRay(rayToScene, scene, sharedRayCount);
        renderTarget.setPixel(x, y, rayToScene.color.clamped());
      }
      sharedPixelCount += 4096;
    }
}
```

It's not really clear why `sharedPixelCount` needs to be updated inside of this loop at all, since it is not referenced in the loop body.  If this is correct, I suggest the following instead.

```
void Raytracer::trace(RenderTarget& renderTarget, const Scene& scene, std::atomic<int>& sharedPixelCount, std::atomic<int>& sharedRayCount)
{
    int width = renderTarget.getWidth();
    int height = renderTarget.getHeight();
    int totalPixelCount = width * height;

    int reducePixelCount = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 4096) \
                         reduction(+:reducePixelCount) \
                         shared(reducePixelCount)
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPixelCount; ++i)
    {
        int x = i % width;
        int y = i / width;

        Ray rayToScene = scene.camera.getRay(x, y);
        shootRay(rayToScene, scene, sharedRayCount);
        renderTarget.setPixel(x, y, rayToScene.color.clamped());

        ++reducePixelCount; /* thread-local operation, not atomic */
    }

    /* The interoperability of C++11 atomics and OpenMP is not defined yet,
     * so this should just be avoided until OpenMP 5 at the earliest. 
     * It is sufficient to reduce over a non-atomic type and 
     * do the assignment here. */
    sharedPixelCount = reducePixelCount;
}
```